# Vue component using axios to update a preference

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to update a preference, example UI attached. The default is yes but a user should have the option to select no. I know I am a little way off but I just need some help identifying where I am going wrong, any help would be really appreciated.

[image]

Parent:

```
        <CommunicationPreference
          v-for="(communication, index) in communicationPreferenceType"
          :key="index + communication.name"
          :consent="communication.consent"
          :name="communication.name"
          @accept-consent="acceptConsent"
          @decline-consent="declineConsent"
        />

  methods: {
    async acceptConsent() {
      await this.$store.dispatch('account/updateCommunicationPreferences')
    },
    async declineConsent() {
      await this.$store.dispatch('account/updateCommunicationPreferences')
    },
}
```

CommunicationPreference.vue component:

```
      <Button
        :text="Yes"
        :type="consent === true ? 'primary' : 'secondary'"
        @clicked="acceptConsent"
      />
      <Button
        :text="No"
        :type="consent !== true ? 'primary' : 'secondary'"
        @clicked="declineConsent"
      />


  methods: {
    acceptConsent(consent) {
      this.$emit('accept', consent === true)
    },
    declineConsent(consent) {
      this.$emit('decline', consent === false)
    },
```

},

Store:

```
 async updateCommunicationPreferences({ commit, state }) {
    const { communicationTypeName } = state.communicationTypeName

    if (!communicationTypeName) {
      return
    }

    try {
      const response = await this.$axios.put(`/communication-consent/${communicationTypeName}`)
      const { data: updatedCommunicationPreferences } = response.data

      commit('SET_UPDATED_COMMUNICATION_PREFERENCES', updatedCommunicationPreferences)
    } catch (error) {
      commit('ADD_ERROR', { id: 'updateCommunicationPreferences', error }, { root: true })
    }
  },
```

Comment: Seems that the method that you are calling on `CommunicationPreference` component, at event `@accept-consent="accept"` is wrong, it should be  `acceptConsent`, I think is a typo error. The same occurs for `@decline-consent="decline"`, the method should be `declineConsent`. Just check the declared method names.

Comment: To add to this comment.  You are not sending in data with your dispatch. So you are not doing anything with the data that you emit from your child component.

Comment: thanks @qimolin would you be able to explain this with an example? I understand what you are saying but not sure how to implement

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the name of the method called is incorrect.
As mentioned by @qimolin, the values related to each option are not being passed to the function that saves it, this can be done by passing a value at calling the action.

```
methods: {
    async acceptConsent() {
      await this.$store.dispatch('account/updateCommunicationPreferences', { consent: true })
    },
    async declineConsent() {
      await this.$store.dispatch('account/updateCommunicationPreferences', { consent: false })
    }
```

or even that simplified with a single method

```
<CommunicationPreference
          v-for="(communication, index) in communicationPreferenceType"
          :key="index + communication.name"
          :consent="communication.consent"
          :name="communication.name"
          @accept-consent="acceptConsent(true)"
          @decline-consent="declineConsent(false)"
        />
```

```
methods: {
  async updateConsent(consent) {
      await this.$store.dispatch('account/updateCommunicationPreferences', { consent })
    }
}
```

and that parameter must be captured on action

```
async updateCommunicationPreferences({ commit, state }, payload) {
    const { consent } = payload // true or false. This is the value selected  by the user.

    const { communicationTypeName } = state.communicationTypeName

    if (!communicationTypeName) {
      return
    }

    try {
      const response = await this.$axios.put(`/communication-consent/${communicationTypeName}`)
      const { data: updatedCommunicationPreferences } = response.data

      commit('SET_UPDATED_COMMUNICATION_PREFERENCES', updatedCommunicationPreferences)
    } catch (error) {
      commit('ADD_ERROR', { id: 'updateCommunicationPreferences', error }, { root: true })
    }
  },
```